# Laravel Livewire Authorization Security

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

When using a full page livewire component, is it sufficient to put the authorization in the route, or should you also have authorization in the component class itself?

For example I have a route such as this:

```
Route::middleware(['can:business.create'])->get('create',\App\Http\Livewire\Business\Create::class)->name('business.create');
```

In this route we use the "can:" middlewire to check if the user has the "business.create" permission.

Do I need to put any `$this->authorize()` into the `function mount` on my Business livewire component?

For example:

```
use AuthorizesRequests;

public function mount(){
    $this->authorize('can', 'business.create');
}
```

To me this looks redundant and unnecessary, but I'm not sure how the livewire behind-the-scenes api works, and if someone can hit the api backend directly and skip the route file middlewire?

Comment: You can do either-or, but doing both is a bit too much, indeed. I would recommend putting it on the component only, but that's my preference, as then it doesn't matter if several routes reuse the same component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would *highly recommend* to use it inside the `mount()` because livewire is meant to be used as components, **resuable components**.

This way you won't have to repeat the **middleware logic for both the route files**.